# convert "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" to DateTime datatype

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I use this code for convert "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" to DateTime datatype in C#:

```
string PurchaseDate == "2017-12-12T14:29:26Z";
datetime dt =  DateTime.ParseExact(PurchaseDate , "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", null);
```

i expect, dt fills with {12/12/2017 14:29:26 PM} but it fills with {12/12/2017 5:59:26 PM} !  why it change this time ?

Comment: you expect 14:29:26 PM?? 14hrs is 24hrs format, so there is no am or pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing Z refers to the Zulu time. Zulu time is equivalent to the UTC (see  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) for further reference)

The parsing you're doing converts the datetime into the "local" timezone.

Comment: I thing Z refer to UTC time . isn't it ??

Comment: Yes that's true. I've just edited the answer to better clarify this.

Comment: I need it return UTC time zone (wthout into the "local" timezone) ! is it possible ?

Comment: How it can parse it to my time zone ! i can parse it !

Comment: You can use [touniversaltime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! its Worke!